# Primefaces ViewScoped and commandButton not working

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, commandbutton

I am developing an aplication in Primefaces and I have a problem with the command button treatment with a viewScoped bean.

I am trying to pass an ID from a page to another page, so just to receive it everytime somebody whants to see the detail of differents clients, this ID must be passed in the URL.

I receive it as follows:

```
<f:metadata>  
        <f:viewParam id="clientId" name="clientId" value="#{perfilClienteSeleccionadoBean.clientId}" />  
    </f:metadata>
```

That form of receiving the data works fine for me, but the problem is when in the same bean, where I have defined that clientId I am trying to call it with a commandButton. This commandButton doesn´t have the values inserted on the view.

My code shows as follows.

My bean:

```
 @Named(value = "perfilClienteSeleccionadoBean")
 @ViewScoped
 public class PerfilClienteSeleccionadoBean implements Serializable {


private FacesMessage msgClienteSeleccionado;  
private Cliente cliente = new Cliente();     
private String clientId;     
private boolean nuevoCliente = true;   
 @PostConstruct
public void cargaInicial(){

    if (strClientId.equalsIgnoreCase("NULL")) {
        nuevoCliente = true;
        System.out.print("*****************IF********************");

    } else {//No es nuevo cliente
        System.out.print("*****************Else********************");
        nuevoCliente = false;
        ClientesDao clienteDao = new ClientesDaoImpl();
        cliente = clienteDao.findByDni(strClientId);



    }
}
 public FacesMessage getMsgClienteSeleccionado() {
    return msgClienteSeleccionado;
}

public void setMsgClienteSeleccionado(FacesMessage msgClienteSeleccionado) {
    this.msgClienteSeleccionado = msgClienteSeleccionado;
}

public String getClientId() {
    return clientId;
}

public void setClientId(String clientId) {
    this.clientId = clientId;
}

public Cliente getCliente() {
    return cliente;
}

public void setCliente(Cliente cliente) {
    this.cliente = cliente;
}

public boolean isNuevoCliente() {
    return nuevoCliente;
}

public void setNuevoCliente(boolean nuevoCliente) {
    this.nuevoCliente = nuevoCliente;
}
public void altaCliente() {
    System.out.print("*****************altaCliente********************");
}
 public void updateCliente() {
    System.out.print("***********************updateCliente****************");
}
}
```

The .xhtml:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
  xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
  xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
  xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core">


<h:head>
    <title>Perfil Cliente</title>
</h:head>

<f:metadata>  
    <f:viewParam id="clientId" name="clientId" value="#{perfilClienteSeleccionadoBean.clientId}" />  
</f:metadata>  

<h:body>
    <ui:composition template="./comun/Plantilla.xhtml">
        <ui:define name="content">
            <h:form id="mensajesCliente">
                <p:messages id="msgClienteSeleccionado" showDetail="true" closable="true" />   
            </h:form>
            <h:form id="formClienteSeleccionado">
                <div align="center">
                    <p:panel header="Perfil Usuario" >

                        <p:panelGrid columns="2" style="width: 50%">
                            <h:outputText value="DNI:"/>
                            <p:inputText id="dniCliente" value="#{perfilClienteSeleccionadoBean.cliente.dniCliente}" size="50" maxlength="9" disabled="#{!perfilClienteSeleccionadoBean.nuevoCliente}" style="font-weight:bold"/>

                            <h:outputText value="Nombre:"/>
                            <p:inputText id="nombreCliente" value="#{perfilClienteSeleccionadoBean.cliente.nombre}" size="50" maxlength="50" disabled="#{!perfilClienteSeleccionadoBean.nuevoCliente}" style="font-weight:bold"/>

                            <h:outputText value="Primer apellido:"/>
                            <p:inputText id="apellido1Cliente" value="#{perfilClienteSeleccionadoBean.cliente.apellido1}" size="50" maxlength="50" disabled="#{!perfilClienteSeleccionadoBean.nuevoCliente}" style="font-weight:bold"/>

                            <h:outputText value="Segundo apellido:"/>
                            <p:inputText id="apellido2Cliente" value="#{perfilClienteSeleccionadoBean.cliente.apellido2}" size="50" maxlength="50" disabled="#{!perfilClienteSeleccionadoBean.nuevoCliente}" style="font-weight:bold"/>



                        </p:panelGrid>

                    </p:panel>
                </div>
    <div align="center" style="width: 95%!important">
                            <p:commandButton id="AltaCliente" update=":formClienteSeleccionado, :mensajesCliente"  value="Alta cliente" actionListener="#{perfilClienteSeleccionadoBean.altaCliente}"  styleClass="ui-priority-primary" process="@all" rendered="#{perfilClienteSeleccionadoBean.nuevoCliente}"/> 
                            <p:commandButton id="UpdateCliente" update=":formClienteSeleccionado, :mensajesCliente"  value="Actualizar cliente" actionListener="#{perfilClienteSeleccionadoBean.updateCliente}"  styleClass="ui-priority-primary" process="@all" rendered="#{!perfilClienteSeleccionadoBean.nuevoCliente}"/> 
                          </div>

            </h:form>
        </ui:define>

    </ui:composition>


</h:body>
```

So my questions are:

- ¿How can i pass a value from a page to another page, just to receive it and not using a @viewScoped or @requestScoped bean? I know that if the bean is @viewScoped or @requestScoped it is executed everytime that the view is charged, I need my bean to execute that way because in de @postConstruct I am capturing the clientID.
- ¿If i use a @viewScopedBean, how can I call to a button in my .xhtml page and read all the data typed in the page?

Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 0):

You can do what you want using ELFlash, here is a simple tutorial:
http://mkblog.exadel.com/2010/07/learning-jsf2-using-flash-scope/